# how can I validate input using an array and display the output in another form in a VB app

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am a beginner in programming. so our homework is to create an app that has 20 TextBoxes which let the user enter the answer for the question. I am given an array of correct answers for each question. so the assignment is to check if the user has entered the correct answer into each textbox (for example, answer in textbox1 should match the FIRST value stored in an array and so on). also, the user can only enter the A,B,C, or D into the textbox; otherwise displays an error. Also, teacher wants us to display the results in another form. So I have been trying to do it for maybe 4 hours now and I tried everything (procedures, functions....) nothing works yet. so far I wrote this code:

```
Public Class MainForm
Public answers() As String = {"B", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A"}
Private Sub btnScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnScore.Click
    If txt1.Text <> answers(0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter either A, B, C, or D")
    Else
        Dim frmResults As New ResultsForm
        frmResults.Show()
        frmResults.lstResults.Items.Add("The correct answer is " & answers(0) & ". Your answer is " & answers(0))
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

So I tried using procedure and function for input validation but they throw an exception of "Cannot convert String to Boolean"....
Does anyone have suggestions how to write code for this app? Thanks.

Comment: First: frmResults.Show() should be the last statement in the Else-block. Second: which line throws the exception?

Comment: none of these particular functions throw an exception but when I tried using function such as this for input validation:                              Private Function InputValidation()
        For Each txt As TextBox In Me.Controls
            If txt.Text <> "A" Or txt.Text <> "B" Or txt.Text <> "C" Or txt.Text <> "D" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Enter either A, B, C, or D")
                Return False
            End If
        Next
        Return True
    End Function '---------------I cannot use it because it throws an exception

Comment: please show the exact code throwing the error; VS should tell you where the exception is.

Comment: sorry, VS does not throw an exception, I meant whatever I input into the textboxes, it always Returns False and and shows that MessageBox

Comment: Seems you have Option Strict On. Good decision. Change the header of the function to: Private Function InputValidation() As Boolean. And: try to change the "Or" to "AndAlso"

Answer (score 0):

So I solved problems with exceptions and wrote the correct input validation function that works:

```
Private Function InputValidation(ByVal input As String) As Boolean
    'input validation function
    If Not input = "A" Then
        If Not input = "B" Then
            If Not input = "C" Then
                If Not input = "D" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter either A, B, C, or D")
                    Return False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```